# Unmerge cells when using groupby (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas

I grouped some data using groupby:

```
df1['N° of options'] = df.groupby(['Country','Restaurant']).Food.size()
```

And the result is a dataframe with grouped arguments merged, instead of it I'd like to repeat these values along the cells.

Any clue about how can I display data like this?
For now, I got something like this:

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `grouped_df` is your grouped dataframe, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to fill down the rows of your two indexes.

##### >>> `print(grouped_df)`

[image]

##### >>> `print(grouped_df.reset_index())`

[image]

Another way to do it is to add `as_index=False` argument to your groupyby clause :

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['SG_UF', 'SG_PARTIDO'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to `sort` instead of `groupby` as you have mentioned you want to **see the values**.

`sort` works like `df_name.sort_values(by column_name, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind=’quicksort’, na_position=’last’, ignore_index=False, key=None)`

In your code, it could look like:

`df.sort_values(by = ['Country','Restaurant'])`. Use other arguments as required, like, order of sort, etc.